# Minimum numbers of elements of a partition of $\ell$-separated sets

Tags: combinatorics

Given a positive integers $n,\ell\ge1$, and given a subset $L$ of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, I say that $L$ is $\ell$-separated if there is an ordering of its elements $a_1,a_2,\dots,a_k$ such that $a_{j+1}-a_j\ge\ell$ for all $j=1,\dots,k-1$. Clearly, every singleton is $\ell$-separated. For example $\{2,5,7,11\}$ is a $2$-separated set, but not 3-separated.

I would like to find the minimum integer possible such that there is a partition of the set $\{1,\dots,n\}$ of $\ell$-separated sets with each of the sets of the partitions having at most $d$ elements, where $d$ is a fixed integer.

Clearly if $n=1$ or $\ell=1$ or $d=1$ the answer is obvious.

Any help is appreciated.